# How to change version of git used to receive git-push over SSH

Tags: git, ssh

My goal is to write code on my laptop and then push to an SSH remote where I can run the more computationally intensive scripts.

```
[my_laptop]$ git remote -v
my_remote   ssh://username@server.com:/home/username/projects/my_project (fetch)
my_remote   ssh://username@server.com:/home/username/projects/my_project (push)
origin  git@github.com:username/my_project.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:username/my_project.git (push)
```

The SSH remote has git 1.7.1 preinstalled (CentOS), but I would like to set the git config option `receive.denyCurrentBranch` to `updateInstead`, which was introduced in git 2.3.0.

I installed git 2.9.5 from source on the remote server and set an alias `git=/home/username/bin/git2` which I can verify as using git 2.9.5.

```
[server]$ which git
alias git='git2'
    ~/bin/git2

[server]$ git --version
git version 2.9.5
```

However, when I try to push from my laptop to the remote I receive a "bad config value" error:

```
[my_laptop]$ git push my_remote my_branch
fatal: bad config value for 'receive.denycurrentbranch' in ./config
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I believe this is because my `git push` is being received with git 1.7.1 rather than 2.9.5.

```
[my_laptop]$ ssh -t username@server.com "git --version"
git version 1.7.1
Connection to server.com closed.

[my_laptop]$ ssh -t username@server.com "git2 --version"
git version 2.9.5
Connection to server.com closed.
```

How can I set the "default" version of git on the SSH server to use 2.9.5 rather than 1.7.1? I do not have admin privileges on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the PATH in a .bash_profile would work only if the sshd (SSH daemon) on your server has the `PermitUserEnvironment` in `sshd_config`, as [mentioned here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332534/7490).

See if you can specify the path of receive-pack if the setting [`remote.<name>.receivepack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-remoteltnamegtreceivepack)

```
git -c remote.origin.receivepack=/home/username/git2/bin/git-receive-pack push my_remote my_branch
```